# connection reset for concurrent usage by two users GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to access same python web app in GAE from firefox and IE with different user login and when I start the IE session I get the following error with IE going standstill.
why?

```
error: (10054, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse creates multiple instances on range of ports and few of them conflicts with pythons working. I could not locate the exact port or did not know how to stop eclipse from doing so. I did simple netstat and observed this behavior of port capturing and causing reset

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is on the dev_appserver? Bear in mind that the dev_appserver is single-threaded, so it will not handle multiple concurrent users well.

Can you give more detail about exactly what sequence of operations causes this? Are there any stack traces on the dev_appserver console when it happens?

Comment: you are probably close to answer but i guess it was also to do with some issues with eclipse too as it opens up many ports on similar range and could be causing this

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a similar outcome when you start the IE session first, then the Firefox session? what about trying two IE sessions, two Firefox sessions, that why you can rule in/out browser differences.

Comment: there is no reset if I go from IE to firefox, two sessions of same browser allows only a single user login, both session point to same login, One user can do certain changes in his role while other cannot